# Running SSIS packages from Tidal Enterprise Scheduler

Tags: ssis, sql-job, tidal-scheduler

Are there any tutorial on how to execute SSIS packages from Tidal Scheduler.

The SSIS packages are on the db server. Is there a way to call SQL job from Tidal using MSSQL Adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Surely you found out how by now, but the Tidal MSSQL Adapter can run any defined job on a SQL Server agent. So you still define your SQL Server SSIS job as normal in SQL Server except don't assign a run schedule to it except back in Tidal. You define your SQL Server as an agent and then define a job step that runs the agent.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the MSSQL Adapter to kickoff your SQL job.  You could use a command-line Tidal job and just run an `osql` or `sqlcmd`.